# Learning road map for functional programming from the viewpoint of category theory

Tags: reference-request, functional-programming, advice-request, ct.category-theory

I am now considering about studying functional programming from the viewpoint of category theory. There are a lot of books about functional programming and category theory, I want some suggestions regarding some comprehensive books and reference materials (like online notes, courses etc)that would contain category theory viewpoint rather than plain functional programming. I have a solid background in Abstract Algebra,commutative algebra, functional programming and bit of category theory too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no agreed upon "bible" for CT for computer science in the same way as for mathematicians ([Mac Lane](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387984038)), probably because the field is younger and a bit broader. It really depends on whether you want to understand . Here are a few computer science concepts with category theory counterparts:

- Simple types (which correspond to [Cartesian Closed Categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category))
- dependent types ([Locally Cartesian Closed Categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+cartesian+closed+category))
- Abstract data types (categorical algebras, coalgebras, as described in e.g. [Uustalu & Vene](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.174.8390&rep=rep1&type=pdf))
- Programing with effects (Monads, monoidal categories, building on the foundational observations of [Moggi](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~crary/819-f09/Moggi91.pdf))
- Ressource aware programing (Closed Monoidal Categories (?))
- CPS translations can be interpreted through the lens of the [Yoneda lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma) (see [here](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2008/01/the_continuation_passing_trans.html) for a brief explanation)

I'm missing a few, there are applications of category theory from everything to domain theory to database management.